# Issue to export images from rosbag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm recording images from /camera/image_raw to rosbag file but when I want to extract them I get gray images with little squares like a grid on them:

[image: image description]

I tried command line and launch file to record:

```
rosbag record -O subset /camera/image_raw
```

and launch file to extract the images but I get the same thing:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 2 $(find ownpackagereco)/bags/subset.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I can visualize the images from the topic while they're publishing and I can see the RGB image correctly

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274483/issue-to-export-images-from-rosbag-file/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2017-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried [image_saver](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view#image_view.2BAC8-diamondback.image_saver)? It includes an `encoding` parameter that could allow you to explicitly set it as RGB or BGR.

---

Originally posted by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) with karma: 136 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-30**:
`image_saver` works but I want to save all my topics in a bag file, it is more easy and practical

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-30**:
Couldn't `image_saver` work on a playing bag file? I guess I don't understand the difference between `image_saver` and `extract_images`, they seem almost interchangeable to me.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-30**:
Oh okay I understand, I changed `extract_images` with `image_saver` in my launch file. Now it works!

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-30**:
I'm glad it works!